# MongoDB: How to compare two documents?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

For example I have this collection:

```
Posts = new Mongo.Collection('posts');

Posts.insert({
  name: "One",
  age: 25,
  ...etc.
});


Posts.insert({
  name: "Two",
  age: 29,
  ...etc.
});
```

And how i can compare my **first** insert document with the **second** ??

I try to search about it but all I can found is "**How to compare fields**" not all document

**ADD :**

How to get **true** if my collection (Posts) contains my first insert document, with or without `Underscore.js`   **?**

```
Posts.insert({
  name: "One",
  age: 25,
  ...etc.
});
```

Comment: Compare the fields in what way?

Comment: Soory don't understand, but i need to compare not fields but my 1 post with second , like compare all fields in both

Comment: Do you want to check if the two documents are "equal" (all fields are the same), or do you need something that tells you which fields are different? Does the function need to deal with nested fields? Comparison is a complex topic - you need to be very specific about what you want.

Comment: @DavidWeldon you absolutlely right, I need to check if two document are "equal"

Comment: @DavidWeldon 
 
but how to get for example true if my collection contains postId1 ? Like `_.contains(Posts,postId1)`

Comment: Generally you use mongo to query for those things like that. I'd recommend opening a new question and giving a very specific use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To compare if two documents are "equal" you can use underscore's [_.isEqual](http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual) like this:

```js
var postId1 = Posts.insert({...});
var postId2 = Posts.insert({...});

var post1 = Posts.findOne(postId1);
var post2 = Posts.findOne(postId2);

console.log(_.isEqual(post1, post2));
```

Comment: but how to get for example true if my collection contains postId1 ?
`Like _.contains(Posts,postId1)`